# PHP : How to emulate format json_encode to text which contain html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

I have an array, this array fill with values from database, some of the value contains html tags.

I need to echo this array as json format, so I am using json_encode to do that.

The problem is, when I try to replicate json format (because I need the json to be simpler). **I can not replicate value which have html tags.**

example:

- original value from database

> ```
>  <span style='font-size:12px'> 25 - 35 " </span><p><span style='font-size:12px'> 
>   </span>
> ```

- after json_encode(**this is what i want it to be**)

> \r\n 25 - 35 \" </span>  \r\n </span>

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a little more context here: what do you currently get after the json_encode? Also what do mean by "replicate"?

Comment: I have an array, but I need this array to be a JSON format, so I use json_encode to encode my array to JSON. its done

Comment: continuation from my comment on above. Because i need to remove some value from my array, so i decide to manually create JSON output by using string combined with foreach and passing my array into it. when i echo ing it to the browser it has same format as my json_encode format, but not with the value which contain html tags on it. it only display 25 - 35 "

Comment: "replicate" mean I manually create JSON output, not using json_encode

Comment: Why do you not want to use `json_encode`? IMO, `json_encode`s output is already as simple as it can be, so what exactly do you mean by "simpler"?

Comment: because I need to remove some value from it

Comment: @rabarday can't you remove/modify the value from PHP array and then json_encode result? It would be easier

Comment: What I ask is how to change my html tags into something like this \r\n 25 - 35 \" </span> \r\n </span>, I can easily change from my array but in the end I wont learn anything new

Answer (score 0):

You could try using htmlentities() on each element before building your json string, but i would agree with commenters that you should just create a new array from your old one with only the values you want, then json_encode that.